# Measure text height (with own font)

Tags: java, android, text, fonts, measure

I am programming a game for Android and need to find out the height of a text, to place
the text correctly.

I am drawing on a canvas in a SurfaceView like this:

```
paint.setTypeface(tfSign);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setTextSize(24);

    canvas.drawText("Level", table[1].getX(), table[1].getY()+measureTextHeight("Level " + Integer.toString(plant[currentViewPoint - 1].getLevel()), paint), paint);
```

as you can see, I am using a method to measure the text height:

```
public int measureTextHeight(String text, Paint paint) {
    Rect result = new Rect();
    // Measure the text rectangle to get the height
    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), result);
    return result.height();
}
```

But this method seem to return a false height.
I think it's because i am using a custom font?

Hope you can say me, how i can get the right Text height!
Thanks :)

Comment: have you tried paint.getFontMetrics? as in example P is below the baseline, as is g, where H is all above the base line it might read false

Comment: i think your code is correct but you are calling it in a wrong place. You should call all measurement properties of any view after its requestlayout() is called. if you call any function like getNumberoflines if the view is not placed yet you will get either false or null

Comment: No, i dont tried getFontMetrics. Could u give me an code-example please?